Generating sequence number from linq2db without materialization
I have a method that gets items and assigns sequence number. Sequence number correspondes to the item's number ordered by TurnedOffOn field.
public IQueryable<RequestLog> Query(bool includeRelated = false)
{
    var allItems = _context.GetTable<RequestLog>().AsQueryable();

    if (includeRelated)
    {
        allItems = allItems
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.Addresses)
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.TurnedOffObjects)
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.Executor)
            .LoadWith(r => r.District)
            .LoadWith(r => r.RospotrebnadzorNotes);
    }

    var orderedItems = allItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn);

    var numberedItems = orderedItems.ToArray();

    for ( var i = 0; i< numberedItems.Length; i++)
    {
        numberedItems[i].SequenceNumber = i + 1;
    }

    return numberedItems.AsQueryable();
}

I want to generate sequence number without materialozation, or using ToArray(). I use linq2db, and tried different ways, and nothing worked so far
For example, this gives exception:
var orderedItems = allItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn);

var sequenceNumber = 0;
foreach (var item in orderedItems)
{
    item.SequenceNumber = sequenceNumber++;
}

return orderedItems;

And this gives exception also - index out of range
public IQueryable<RequestLog> Query(bool includeRelated = false)
{
    var allItems = _context.GetTable<RequestLog>().AsQueryable();

    if (includeRelated)
    {
        allItems = allItems
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.Addresses)
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.TurnedOffObjects)
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.Executor)
            .LoadWith(r => r.District)
            .LoadWith(r => r.RospotrebnadzorNotes);
    }

    var orderedItems = allItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn);

    return orderedItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn)
         .Select((log, index) => new RequestLog // create a new instance to avoid in memory changes
         {
             Id = log.Id,
             SequenceNumber = index + 1,
             // other fields
         }).AsQueryable();
}

Addition:
I get this query
var query = _store.RequestsLog.Query(true).Where(filter);

from repository method
public IQueryable<RequestLog> Query(bool includeRelated = false)
{
    var allItems = _context.GetTable<RequestLog>().AsQueryable();

    if (includeRelated)
    {
        allItems = allItems
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.Addresses)
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.TurnedOffObjects)
            .LoadWith(r => r.Request).ThenLoad(w => w.Executor)
            .LoadWith(r => r.District)
            .LoadWith(r => r.RospotrebnadzorNotes);
    }

    var orderedItems = allItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn);
    return orderedItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn)
     .Select(log => new RequestLog
     {
         Id = log.Id,
         SequenceNumber = (int)Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over().OrderBy(log.TurnedOffOn).ToValue(),
         //other fields
     });
}

And SqlText of this query is correct, if I run in Management Studio, it doesn't give any error:
SELECT
    [p].[Id],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [p].[TurnedOffOn]),

But here is where exception goes:
var response = OrderItems(query, request.Sort)
    .TakePage(request.Page)
    .ProjectTo<RequestLogViewModel>(RequestLogMappers.Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
    .AsPagedList(totalCount);

In method TakePage comes query with following SqlText: "((LinqToDB.Linq.ExpressionQuery<WaterAccidents.DAL.Models.RequestLog>)src).SqlText" выдал исключение типа "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException"
This is method OrderBy, where probably the problem appears:
public static IOrderedQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> src, string propertyName, bool reverse = false)
{
    var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

    if (propertyInfo == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"property {propertyName} not found on object {typeof(T).Name}");

    var keySelector = BuildKeySelector<T>(propertyInfo);
    var targetMethodName = !reverse ? "TargetOrderBy" : "TargetOrderByDescending";
    var methodInfo = typeof(QueryableExtensions).GetMethod(targetMethodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    if (methodInfo == null)
        throw new Exception($"can't bind to generic target method {targetMethodName}");

    var method = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), propertyInfo.PropertyType);

    return method.Invoke(null, new[] {src, keySelector}) as IOrderedQueryable<T>;
}

propertyName being passed to the OrderBy method is correct and exists on the RequestLog class.
And when I inspect inner exception like this
try
{
    response = OrderItems(query, request.Sort)
        .TakePage(request.Page)
        .ProjectTo<RequestLogViewModel>(RequestLogMappers.Mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
        .AsPagedList(totalCount);
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    var innerException = ex.InnerException; 
                                            
}

innerException: Message = "Member 'Ext' not found in type 'FKDH`2'."

linq2db supports Windows Functions and you can use ROW_NUMBER to achive desired sequence
return orderedItems.OrderBy(log => log.TurnedOffOn)
         .Select(log => new RequestLog
         {
             Id = log.Id,
             SequenceNumber = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
                .OderBy(log.TurnedOffOn)
                .ToValue(),
             // other fields
         });


When I do this, I get exception: LinqToDBException: Member 'Ext' not found in type 'FKDH`2'.

I need more context. Can you try it linq2db 6 preview-1 it is more mature than version 5? We paln to release preview-2 in couple of weeks which has also much more translation improvements.

I tried with version 6, it worked. But is it ok to use preview version in production?

It passes all our tests and it is huge number. Why it is not released yet, we still clarifying some minor breacking changes in contracts.

Ok, thanks a lot for your help!

My boss is against preview versions. What could be the reasons it doesn't work with other versions?

I need context. Old LINQ translator may have issues in some cases.

Wrote details in the question. It's probaly about reflection, can't get exactly why, and why not in 6 version

Ensure with part of the query introduces error. If OrderBy, we can fix that, if it is ProjectTo, we have to investigate deeper.
